# php eval not returning an variable from code in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, eval

I am trying to write a website that can do various  checks on the servers.
so have created a table that stores those checks one of which is ping as shown in the code below

```
$pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 $hs", $outcome, $st);
if (0 != $st) 
{
$status='Server Down';

return $status;
}
```

I intented to iterate over this check for servers that have it and other checks. To run this check I run the code below. after quering the database.

```
do
{
$hs= server name
eval($row_schecks['code']);
 echo  $hs.$status;
 } while ($row_schecks = mysql_fetch_assoc($schecks));
```

I never seem to get the $status returned. so I can not tell if the server is up or not.

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like your first call to `$row_schecks['code']` fails due to lack of `$row_schecks` at this moment. Try to use `while-do` loop rather than `do-while`.

Comment: do while is bad to use with fetching db data, you never knows (or in most cases) would you have results or data set would be empty.

Comment: My appolgize I did nto included the db fetch code          mysql_select_db($database_serverstatus, $serverstatus);
    $query_schecks = "select a.code,b.actual_name from     service_checks a,server_checks b where a.id=b.servicecheck and b.runcheck = 1  and b.actual_name ='".$hs."'";
$schecks = mysql_query($query_schecks, $serverstatus) or die(mysql_error());
$row_schecks = mysql_fetch_assoc($schecks);
$totalRows_schecks = mysql_num_rows($schecks);